# Python SQLite, problem with storing keys with multiple values

Tags: python, json, sqlite, request

I'm trying to make a script that monitors [this link](https://www.deadstock.ca/products.json) for new products loaded on the site, and if a new product is found with a unique title, it is stored in a SQLite database, along with the sizes of it. However, when I store it, it only stores on size, not all of the sizes for the product, [this](https://gyazo.com/f596f43ead051e3cf29eb32a62ad31f7) is what it looks like. I don't understand how to store all of the sizes with one key. That way, if a new product loads, it adds the product title, and all the sizes.

I tried adding the sizes to a list and running a for loop through that list and that didn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import random
import sqlite3
import discord
import time
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

link = 'https://deadstock.ca/products.json'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
}
def add_to_db(title, size):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('testing.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Keywordss (titles TEXT UNIQUE, sizes TEXT)''')
    alert = False
    try:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Keywordss (titles, sizes) VALUES (?, ?)', (title, size))
        print(title + ' JUST DROPPED' + time.asctime())

    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        pass
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()


def get_product():
    size_lst = []

    page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    try:
        jsn = page.json()
    except:
        print('the site has temp banned you')
    for product in jsn['products']:
        id = product['id']
        title = product['title']
        sizes = product['variants']
        for size in sizes:
            print(size)
            size = size['title']
            add_to_db(title, size)


get_product()
```

I expect it to add the product title, into the database, and all the sizes with it.

Comment: you will have to remove the `unique` constraint on the title column if you want to do it the way you have designed because currently you only keep the latest regard due to that constraint

Comment: im trying to make it have the title once, and then the all the sizes for that title, not the title for however many sizes there are

Comment: then append all the sizes to a string since you made it a text type and then upload it at once, this seems like bad      design pattern, I would have a reference table with unique titles and an id, and then a separate table with that id and a row for each size